# Final classes in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading

I have question about final classes in Hibernate. reading Hibernate documentation I have read:

> You can persist final classes that do not implement an interface with Hibernate; you will not, however, be able to use proxies for lazy association fetching which will ultimately limit your options for performance tuning.

Then I have developed a simple example, I have created two final classes Foo and Bar. Foo has a one to many relationship to Bar. Foo and Bar are annotated with @Entity and relationship with @OneToMany(mappedBy="foo", cascade={CascadeType.ALL}) and @ManyToOne, at field level access.

Then I create a test, which inserts a Foo and many Bar. Then I find by id a Foo object and then I call getBars() and it acts as a lazy, Hibernate does a query and returns all Bars.

What I am missing?, it is supposed to not create this query because classes are final, but query is executed.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: did you see some proxies set inside the **getBars()** in debug mode?